# Bad Exception on swipe action cell Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, null, segue, exc-bad-instruction

I'm making an app that is sending information about text inside of cells to a WebViewController using swipe actions. The swipe action is:

```
let sendToWebsite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Website")
{ (action, indexPath) in
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
    sendToWebsite.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return [sendToWebsite]
}
```

This works fine but I also have two segues coming from the same View Controller, to two other VC's. The first segue(recipeDetail) is when you tap directly on the cell and works fine, but the second segue(yourSegueIdentifier) is a button that appears when you activate the slide action on the cell and does't work. [image: Cell Swipe Action]

the segues:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "recipeDetail") {
        let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let destinationViewController: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        destinationViewController.recipe = recipes[indexPath!.row]
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier"
    {
        let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let nextVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController

        nextVC.recipe = recipes[indexPath!.row]
    }
}
```

On the line

```
nextVC.recipe = recipes[indexPath!.row]
```

indexPath is coming out as nil and giving the following error message
[image: error on line 13]

Comment: indexPathForSelectedRow is returning nil, probably because your row is not in a selected state. Do you have selection enabled on the table view? Did you implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method? Swiping the row will not automaically place it in a selected state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like on the swipe action, the tableView doesn't register the "indexPathForSelectedRow" method. 
What you could alternatively do is setup a global swipeIndex variable

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

var swipeIndex : Int!
//Code, code, code...
```

and then set it once the swipe action is called.

```
let sendToWebsite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Website")
{ (action, indexPath) in
    self.swipeIndex = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
    sendToWebsite.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    return [sendToWebsite]
}
```

and then:

```
else if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier"
    {
        let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let nextVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController

        nextVC.recipe = recipies[self.swipeIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: how should I setup the swipeIndex variable?

Comment: Right under your class ViewController: UIViewController. Just add: var swipeIndex : Int!

Comment: Edited the answer to better explain :)

Comment: thanks! one more thing, on the last line, nextVC.recipe = self.swipeIndex, there is an error that says "cannot assign value of type 'Int!' to type 'Recipe?'"

Comment: Haha, updated my answer. Please upvote/mark as right answer if this helped :)